# How do I drop a function if it already exists?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2000

I know this must be simple, but how do I preface the creation of a function with a check to see if it already exists? If it exists, I want to drop and re-create it.

Answer (score 206, accepted):

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE id = object_id(N'function_name') 
    AND xtype IN (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF')
)
    DROP FUNCTION function_name
GO
```

If you want to avoid the sys* tables, you could instead do (from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx) in example A):

```
IF object_id(N'function_name', N'FN') IS NOT NULL
    DROP FUNCTION function_name
GO
```

The main thing to catch is what type of function you are trying to delete (denoted in the top sql by FN, IF and TF):

- FN = Scalar Function
- IF = Inlined Table Function
- TF = Table Function

Comment: Hey thanks, I didn't know Object_id had a second parameter for the type of object

Comment: given object names (that appear in sys.objects) have to be unique, querying xtype is redundant. Try creating a table and a stored proc with the same name...

Answer (score 24):

```
if object_id('FUNCTION_NAME') is not NULL
   DROP FUNCTION <name>
```

You can also look the name up in sysobjects

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
       FROM   sysobjects 
           WHERE name='<function name>' and xtype='FN'
```

Actually, if the function could be a table function, you need to use

```
xtype in ('FN','TF')
```

Comment: I've always preferred the Object_id method, it seems simpler to read in the code.   Always curious why the Microsoft generated sample code uses the sys.objects lookup instead...

Answer (score 16):

You have two options to drop and recreate the procedure in SQL Server 2016.

Starting from SQL Server 2016 - use [`IF EXISTS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016#arguments)

```sql
DROP FUNCTION [ IF EXISTS ] { [ schema_name. ] function_name } [ ,...n ]   [;]
```

Starting from SQL Server 2016 SP1 - use [`OR ALTER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#arguments)

```sql
CREATE [ OR ALTER ] FUNCTION [ schema_name. ] function_name
```

Answer (score 15):

This works for **any** object, not just functions:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('YourObjectName') IS NOT NULL
```

then just add your flavor of object, as in:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('YourFunction') IS NOT NULL
   DROP FUNCTION YourFunction
```

Answer (score 7):

From `SQL Server 2016 CTP3` you can use new *DIE*  statements instead of big `IF` wrappers

Syntax :

> DROP FUNCTION [ IF EXISTS ] { [ schema_name. ] function_name } [ ,...n
>   ]

Query:

```
DROP Function IF EXISTS udf_name
```

More info [**here**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190290.aspx)

Answer (score 6):

```
IF EXISTS 
(SELECT * FROM sys.objects 
WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'functionName') 
AND type in (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS', N'FT'))

DROP FUNCTION functionName
GO
```

Answer (score 2):

I usually shy away from queries from sys* type tables, vendors tend to change these between releases, major or otherwise. What I have always done is to issue the `DROP FUNCTION <name>` statement and not worry about any SQL error that might come back.  I consider that standard procedure in the DBA realm.

Comment: sys. in SQL Server 2005 is the official way. They are *views* not tables nowadays and the actual sys tables are hidden from us.

Answer (score 0):

```
IF EXISTS
      (SELECT * 
      FROM schema.sys.objects
      WHERE name = 'func_name')
    DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[func_name]
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on this:

```
if(object_id(N'[dbo].[fn_Nth_Pos]', N'FN')) is not null
    drop function [dbo].[fn_Nth_Pos];
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Nth_Pos]
(
    @find char, --char to find
    @search varchar(max), --string to process   
    @nth int --occurrence   
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    declare @pos int --position of nth occurrence
    --init
    set @pos = 0

    while(@nth > 0)
    begin       
        set @pos = charindex(@find,@search,@pos+1)
        set @nth = @nth - 1
    end 

    return @pos
END
GO

--EXAMPLE
declare @files table(name varchar(max));

insert into @files(name) values('abc_1_2_3_4.gif');
insert into @files(name) values('zzz_12_3_3_45.gif');

select
    f.name,
    dbo.fn_Nth_Pos('_', f.name, 1) as [1st],
    dbo.fn_Nth_Pos('_', f.name, 2) as [2nd],
    dbo.fn_Nth_Pos('_', f.name, 3) as [3rd],
    dbo.fn_Nth_Pos('_', f.name, 4) as [4th]
from 
    @files f;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the SQL ISO standard INFORMATION_SCHEMA and not the SQL Server-specific `sysobjects`, you can do this:

```
IF EXISTS (
    SELECT ROUTINE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_NAME = N'FunctionName'
)
   DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[FunctionName]
GO
```